# partitioning hive table on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop

i have following table

```
 create table stocks
(exchange string,symbol string,date string,open float)
partitioned by (exch string,sym string)
clustered by (date) into 5 buckets
row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

my question is:- how the data is stored in HDFS? 
would it be 5 buckets(sub directories) inside both the partitions(total 10 buckets) or will it be 5 sub directories inside the partition?

I tried creating this program in Hive, but was not success-full.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I wonder where the table is. It would be great if you can provide the table.Then, someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Hi the create statement should looks like below, as DATE is a reserved keyword in Hive I believe.

```
CREATE TABLE stocks(exchange STRING, symbol STRING, day STRING, open FLOAT)
PARTITIONED BY(exch STRING, sym STRING)
CLUSTERED BY(day) INTO 5 BUCKETS ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

In HDFS the directory structure will be:

*/user/hive/warehouse/<DB_NAME>/stocks/day1/bucket1*

so 5 such directories will be there.

You can refer this link if something precisely you are looking for
[What is the difference between partitioning and bucketing a table in Hive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128940/what-is-the-difference-between-partitioning-and-bucketing-a-table-in-hive)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The data stored in HDFS would have 5 directories since 5 buckets. The structure would be like :

```
<hdfs_path>/date1/exch1/sym1
<hdfs_path>/date2/exch2/sym2
<hdfs_path>/date3/exch3/sym3
<hdfs_path>/date4/exch4/sym4
<hdfs_path>/date5/exch5/sym5
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128940/what-is-the-difference-between-partitioning-and-bucketing-a-table-in-hive) for more details.