# Knowing in advance which bucket a Hive row will go

Tags: hadoop, hive

When we have a bucketing defined on a certain column, hive calculates hash value for each unique value for the column and sends rows to these buckets. This might lead to skewed buckets, when hash values for multiple unique values cause them going to the same bucket. Now lets say the bucketed column is country, and the values are like:-

```
country = {'USA','Brazil','Findland','India','England'}
```

Now there is no guarantee that hashing will send all the 5 countries to different buckets (assume number of buckets are 5). Is there any way to know in advance which bucket a row with specific value for country will be sent to? I am looking for something like this:-

```
select know_which_bucket(country,5) from table;
```

It need not be hive function, I am just trying to explain what I am looking for logically, I just need info. Basically i will specify a set of values , number of buckets and want to know which bucket each of the value will go to. If someone can provide Java pointer for this, it will help too. Also, I am not necessarily looking for a programmatic way, even an online calculator will do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How hashing works in bucketing for hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594038/how-hashing-works-in-bucketing-for-hive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, this is how you do it:-

For example, to know which bucket(file) 'USA' will go provided that number of buckets are 5:-

```
select pmod(hash('USA'),5);
```

It returns 3, so this will be stored in the file 00000**3**_0. This way we can know for any input value and for any number of buckets.