# Can bucketing and partitioning be used in the same query in HIVE?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Can bucketing and partitioning be used in the same query in HIVE ?

Comment: There is a great way to find out the answer to this question.  Run a Hive query that has bucketing and partitioning in it.

Comment: Yes. You can have buckets and partition in same HIVE table.

 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128940/what-is-the-difference-between-partitioning-and-bucketing-a-table-in-hive provide good insight into these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Bucketing and partitioning can be applied in the same hive table.

**Partitions:**
Total number of distinct values on partition column = Total number of folders in HDFS path under table name folder.
*To enable, execute*:`set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;`
`set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;`

**Buckets:**
Total number buckets = no. of files under each partition folder. *To enable, execute*: `set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;`

Comment: Please follow proper [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) guidelines for answering questions on stackoverflow.