# Difference between bucketing and partitioning in hive?

Tags: hive, partitioning

What is the difference between bucketing and partitioning?

Where and when to use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128940/what-is-the-difference-between-partitioning-and-bucketing-a-table-in-hive and many other similar queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between partitioning and bucketing a table in Hive ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128940/what-is-the-difference-between-partitioning-and-bucketing-a-table-in-hive)