# Apache Hive Partition & Bucketing Structure

Tags: hive, hiveql

In Apache Hive, how does the directory structure looks after a huge dataset is being partitioned and then bucketed?

For Ex - I have a customer dataset for a country, the data is being partitioned by state and then bucketed by city. How do we get to know how many files will be present in a city bucket?

Answer (score 1):

A partition is a directory, and each partition corresponds to a specific value of the partitioned column.

Within a table or a partition/directory, buckets are organized as files. The number of buckets is predefined when creating a table with `CLUSTERED BY (sth) INTO K BUCKETS`. There will be ONE file for each individual bucket. Hive assigns records to buckets based on their hash value calculated by the bucketed column, and a mod is taken by the num of buckets K.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum number of bucketing is 256 . For more details kindly refer below link:

[[What is the difference between partitioning and bucketing a table in Hive ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128940/what-is-the-difference-between-partitioning-and-bucketing-a-table-in-hive/19131221#19131221][1])